# Do not-precompiled headers use precompiled headers if they are Included or are they for .cpp files only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022:

- I want to Include Precompiled headers in my .cpp file but I don't know if it's worth it since I'll also need to include a non-precompiled header with almost the same headers that are in the precompiled header.
- Will the non-precompiled header use the precompiled headers or will it generate the code again on each compilation?

CPP:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Precompiled.h"
#include "No-Precompiled.h" // Basic Headers: Windows.h, Psapi.h

int main()
{
    // Functions that I need from "No-Precompiled.h" but I can't Precompile it since changes in it are made on regular basis
}
```

No-Precompiled.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>

class Template
{
public:
    //Functions that need many same Headers.
}
```

Precompiled.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <limits>
#include <complex>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wincred.h>
#include <complex>
#include <math.h>
```

- Should I just Precompile the headers that the .cpp file uses (which is not much) or is there a way to allow No-Precompiled headers to use the Precompiled headers?

Comment: It'll re-compile it again and upon link time, you'll get symbol conflicts.

Comment: Not an answer to your question per-se, but a trick to reason about this: Think of pre-compiled headers as just taking a snapshot of the compiler state after compiling the header. It`s literally a *pause* of the compilation process. Nothing fancier than that.

Comment: If your project expects all the source files to include the precompiled header, there is no need to "re-include" stuff in the other header. Doing so will not cause conflicts or "double-inclusion", but it will be a performance hit because those headers must be parsed, even if that results in no extra code due to header guards. In very large projects, removing redundant inclusions like this is one of the strategies for speeding up compilation.

Comment: @paddy Usage of `#pragma once`, as OP is doing, short-circuits the need to re-load the header on subsequent inclusions. I'd argue that, nowadays, maintaining headers that do not require prior inclusions, via pch or otherwise, brings ample maintainability benefit to counteract the performance loss.

Comment: @Frank I'm talking about things like `#include <windows.h>` _etc_ that will be hit for each source file that includes the non-precompiled stuff. In particular, that large header does _not_ use `#pragma once` and will still need to be parsed by the preprocessor even though the guard is set by its inclusion in the precompiled header.

Comment: @paddy Even then, I'd comfortably argue that it should be considered an extreme measure to be taken when compile times are too long and it measurably has a strong impact, not a "by default" practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pre-compiled headers doesn't change that much. In particular, header guards continue to work. The header guard for `<windows.h>` is also included in the pre-compiled state. Hence, when the compiler sees `<windows.h>` for the second time, it's immediately skipped.

In your case, the `No-Precompiled.h` header turns out to be pretty trivial, as all its headers have already been included. You're just compiling the `Template`.

I'd wonder a bit about the particular set of precompiled headers, though. PSapi and DirectX and IOstream? I can't really imagine a big program where you have many files using all of them. Note that `<iostream>` is really about `std::cout`, which doesn't make a lot of sense for DirectX programs.

Comment: "*PSapi and DirectX and IOstream? I can't really imagine a big program where you have many files using all of them.*" The main limitation of precompiled headers is that you can only have one, so you kind of have to shove *everything* into it that you use *anywhere*. That is, you do it if you want the compile-time benefits of them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Visual Studio at least has the ability to have multiple different headers, and IIRC that goes back to at least VS2010. Both `/Yc`  and `/Yu` take an optional filename argument.

Comment: Different PCHs for different *source files*. But each source file can only include one PCH.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Indeed. But that means you can include `<windows.h>` in your GUI.pch and `psapi.h` in your backend.pch. The original claim, "have to shove everything into it that you use anywhere" is much too strong.